# How can I show a div, then hide the other divs when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, html

I am right now trying to hide six divs while showing only one of the divs.  I've tried JavaScript and in jQuery, but nothing seems to work!  Click [here](http://abrielshipley.com/ffi/resources4.html) to get to the website.

I would like to know if it has to do with my CSS, jQuery, or the HTML.  Or is there an easier way of doing this?

HTML:

```
<div id="resourceLinks">
  <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource1">General&nbsp;Information</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource2">Automatic&nbsp;401(k)</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource3">Consumer&nbsp;Fraud</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource4">Direct&nbsp;Deposit</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource5">Diversity</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource6">Women</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource7">Young&nbsp;Adults&nbsp;(20s&nbsp;-&nbsp;40s)</a>
  </div>

<div id="resource1></div>
<div id="resource2></div>
<div id="resource3></div>
<div id="resource4></div>
<div id="resource5></div>
<div id="resource6></div>
<div id="resource7></div>
```

CSS:

```
#resource1, #resource2, #resource3, #resource4, #resource5, #resource6, #resource7 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}

#resourceLinks {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -450px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-top: 180px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $('#resourceLinks a').click(function (selected) { 

    var getName = $(this).attr("id"); 
    var projectImages = $(this).attr("name");

    $(function() {      
      $(".resource").hide().removeClass("current");
      $("#" + projectImages ).show("normal").addClass("current");
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I think you've confused `name` with `class`. Furthermore, `ID` s must be unique. Also, `$(this).attr("id");` can be written as `this.id` (no need to wrap in jQuery).

Comment: html dom id should be unique :)

Comment: What is the objective? To toggle the `current` class between the links in `#resourceLinks` and then display the corresponding `<div>` (`#resource1` through `...7`), hiding the rest?

Comment: @jensgram: I think I might have mixed up class's and names.
@jensgram & @OnesimsusUnbound: I should've realized that I was using the same IDs twice.

Comment: @jensgram: Yes that's exactly what I want.  I apologize for the confusion if there was any.  =]

Comment: Wow I must say all of these answers are all correct, and it's so hard to pick one.  I just want to thank everyone on this post for helping me!  I couldn't have done it without everyone of you.  =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this one

```
<div id="resourceLinks">   
    <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource1">General&nbsp;Information</a><br />   
    <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource2">Automatic&nbsp;401(k)</a><br />   
    <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource3">Consumer&nbsp;Fraud</a><br />   
    <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource4">Direct&nbsp;Deposit</a><br />   
    <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource5">Diversity</a><br />   
    <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource6">Women</a><br />   
    <a href="#" name="resource" id="resource7">Young&nbsp;Adults&nbsp;(20s&nbsp;-&nbsp;40s)</a>   
</div>  

<div class="resource" id="resource1_info"></div> 
<div class="resource" id="resource2_info"></div> 
<div class="resource" id="resource3_info"></div> 
<div class="resource" id="resource4_info"></div> 
<div class="resource" id="resource5_info"></div> 
<div class="resource" id="resource6_info"></div> 
<div class="resource" id="resource7_info"></div> 


$(document).ready(function(){
     $("div.resource:gt(0)").hide();  // to hide all div except for the first one
     $('#resourceLinks a').click(function(selected) {
        var getID = $(this).attr("id");      
        var projectImages = $(this).attr("name");      

        $("div.resource").hide();       
        $("#" + getID + "_info" ).show();    
    });  
});
```

Comment: It's doing like it did before.  It shows the first div initially, but then when you click on a different link, it doesn't show that div.  Once you click back on the first link, it shows the first divs content again.

Comment: see the changes. is it what you're referring to?

Comment: @Omesimus: This is what I was referring to!  With this, it almost works for my purpose.  The only fix this would need is that all of the divs don't show at once when it initially starts up.

Comment: there you go. I though you wanted to have the first div shown on initial load :)

Comment: Hmmm... for some reason it's not showing the first div on initial load (even after I added the edited line).  =/

Comment: ah, so what you mean is that initially it shows all div then suddenly they're hidden? if that so you may set the style of the div (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: Nevermind!  I didn't see you edited the code with the :gt(0) in the $("div.resource:gt(0)").hide(); and now it works!  =]  The only thing that I would like in addition to that is a way how to make the links change size to show the user the active or current div.

Comment: well, that's another question :-).

Comment: That is indeed another question.  =]  I guess with jensgram's answer, it made me curious how I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
<div id="resourceLinks">
  <a href="#" data-child="resource1">General&nbsp;Information</a><br />
  <a href="#" data-child="resource2">Automatic&nbsp;401(k)</a><br />
  <a href="#" data-child="resource3">Consumer&nbsp;Fraud</a><br />
  <a href="#" data-child="resource4">Direct&nbsp;Deposit</a><br />
  <a href="#" data-child="resource5">Diversity</a><br />
  <a href="#" data-child="resource6">Women</a><br />
  <a href="#" data-child="resource7">Young&nbsp;Adults&nbsp;(20s&nbsp;-&nbsp;40s)</a>
  </div>

<div class="resource" id="resource1">1</div>
<div class="resource" id="resource2">2</div>
<div class="resource" id="resource3">3</div>
<div class="resource" id="resource4">4</div>
<div class="resource" id="resource5">5</div>
<div class="resource" id="resource6">6</div>
<div class="resource" id="resource7">7</div>
```

You can:

```
$(function() {
    var $resLinks = $('#resourceLinks a'),
        $res = $('.resource');

    // Hide all but first
    $res.not(':first').hide();
    $resLinks.first().addClass('current');

    $resLinks.click(function() {
        var $elm = $(this),
            childId = $elm.data('child');

        // Hide all (only one is visible, though)
        $res.hide();

        // Reset and set .current class on links
        $resLinks.removeClass('current');
        $elm.addClass('current');

        // Show related
        $('#' + childId).show();

        return false;
    });
});
```

**Update #1:** Code is [tested](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/e6bPS/1/).

**Update #2:** [Showing first on init](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/e6bPS/2/).

Comment: It says that the first line with var $('#resourceLinks a'); isn't valid.

Comment: @Abriel Yeah, sorry. It was a pile of bugs and typos :) Edited to working version. Not necessarily the most elegant solution, though. I aimed for minimal impact on existing markup.

Comment: I see that it's working in your demo, but not working on my site for some reason.  Is there anyway you could change it so the first div is initally showing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve the accordian effect.. Have a look here:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/

Its and existing jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Using classNames

```
<div id="resourceLinks">
      <a href="#" class="resource1">General Information</a><br />
      <a href="#" class="resource2">Automatic</a><br />
      <a href="#" class="resource3">Consumer Fraud</a><br />
      <a href="#" class="resource4">Direct Deposit</a><br />
      <a href="#" class="resource5">Diversity</a><br />
      <a href="#" class="resource6">Women</a><br />
      <a href="#" class="resource7">Young</a>
</div>
<div class="resources">
    <div id="resource1" class="current"></div>
    <div id="resource2"></div>
    <div id="resource3"></div>
    <div id="resource4"></div>
    <div id="resource5"></div>
    <div id="resource6"></div>
    <div id="resource7"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#resourceLinks a').click(function() {
        $('div.resources div').hide().removeClass('current');       
        $("#" + $(this).attr('className')).show().addClass('current');
    });  
});
```